# Initializing map of string and vector correctly

Tags: c++, memory, vector, data-structures, insert

I have a `map<std::string, std::vector<string>> myMap` which is a member of the class. This map is supposed to get filled in 2 steps after the object is created. Since the size of the map is not known, I am not initializing it in the constructor of the class. What I am doing is the following :

```
//Step1
//Just adding the keys to the map
if(condition)
    myMap[strCondition];

//do something
//do something else

//Step2
//Adding the values to the keys
std::vector<std::string> tokens;
//tokens get filled
if(anotherCondition)
    myMap[strCondition].insert(myMap[strCondition].end(), tokens.begin(), tokens.end());
```

Is this the correct and efficient way of doing this ? Could some piece of code between steps 1 and steps 2 accessing `myMap` key value pairs cause the program to crash since the `myMap` values (std::vectors) are not there? Also can I just get rid of step1 as step2 will anyway add the key to the map if it doesn't exist already.

Comment: 1) Seems to be, but you could **profile** the code to verify. 2) Sure, it could... since we have to guess what that omitted code is doing, I can imagine there could be some code that would crash there. 3) Maybe, the condition and anotherCondition variables are different, so dropping the first would change the behavior.

Comment: `myMap[strCondition].insert(myMap[strCondition].end(), ..)` does 2 lookup, `auto& v = myMap[strCondition]; v.insert(v.end(), ..);` would do it only once.

Comment: Without "step1", `myMap.at(strCondition)` would throw, and `myMap.find(strCondition)` would return `myMap.end()`.

Comment: Absent key, and present with default value are 2 different things that can be checked independently. For your usage, it might be possible you consider the 2 states as identical though.

Comment: you cannot add only keys to the map. An element of the map is always a `std::pair<const Key,MappedType>`. There is no way an element could be accessed but no vector is present. The vector could be empty though, maybe thats what you mean

Answer (score 0):

What you're doing is more or less correct, but there's an unnecessary source of inefficiency. You look up `myMap[strCondition]` multiple times, when once would suffice:

```cpp
std::vector<T>* p = nullptr;

if(condition)
    p = &myMap[strCondition];

// ...

if(anotherCondition) {
    p = p == nullptr ? &myMap[strCondition] : p;
    // since C++23
    p->append_range(tokens);
    // until C++23
    p->insert(e->end(), tokens.begin(), tokens.end());
}
```

Note that this code assumes that no vector should be created in the map when `!condition && !anotherCondition`.
If it's permitted to make a new vector no matter what, you could simplify the code, and store

```cpp
auto& ref = myMap[strCondition];
```

... once at the start.

> Could some piece of code between steps 1 and steps 2 accessing myMap key value pairs cause the program to crash since the myMap values (std::vectors) are not there?

No. `myMap[strCondition]` is safe to use in step 2, no matter what happened previously.

> Also can I just get rid of step1 as step2 will anyway add the key to the map if it doesn't exist already.

If it's not necessary to construct an empty vector no matter what `anotherCondition` is, then yes. It's safe to write `myMap[strCondition].append_range` in step 2, even if `strCondition` didn't previously exist as  a key yet.